# tolua++ Calling Lua function from C++ code

Tags: c++, lua, tolua++

I am trying to use tolua++ library for embedding Lua script to my c++ application. It is clear for me, how to bind C++ classes to Lua, create them from Lua script and call methods.  However, I can't really take in how to call Lua script functions from C++ (with passing arguments and getting return value).

Can you please say the standard way for doing this using tolua++? Does tolua++ cover that, or I have to use Lua C Api?

Answer (score 0):

You should use CAPI, it's like the following:

in lua:

```
function showValue(strFirstName, strLastName)
     strName = strFirstName .. "." .. strLastName
     print(strName)
     return strName, "is", 18
end
```

in c++:

```
  lua_getglobal(L, "showValue");
  lua_pushstring(L, "William");
  lua_pushstring(L, "Hsueh");

  lua_pcall(L, 2, 3, 0);

  // get return values
  int nOld = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
  const char *pIs = lua_tostring(L, -2);
  const char *pName = lua_tostring(L, -3);
```

you can check the whole example at: http://blog.deskangel.com/?p=459

the post of the link is in Chinese, but the code says everything.

Comment: I don't think it is the solution.

Comment: @einverne, so, what's your solution?